# Keyboard not being dismissed with Keyboard.dismiss in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, keyboard, expo

I'm looking to dismiss the keyboard when the user clicks on anywhere outside the keyboard or the input, but the keyboard is not being dismissed when I click elsewhere:

```js
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback style={styles.container} onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder="Search Term"
                    style={styles.input}
                    onChangeText={setSearch}
                    value={search}
                    returnKeyType="search"
                    onSubmitEditing={handleSubmit}
                />
            </View>
        </ TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

The styling is pretty standard:

```js
   container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    inputContainer: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: stackHeaderHeight + 10,
        height: height * .1,
        width: '100%',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your `onPress` code of `TouchableWithoutFeedback`

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback style={styles.container} onPress={()=> Keyboard.dismiss()}>

        </ TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Sample working code.

```
render() {
return (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={()=>Keyboard.dismiss()} >
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <TextInput returnKeyType="search" style={{borderWidth:1,borderColor:'grey',marginTop:100,height:50,marginHorizontal:50}}/>
    </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
}
```

I think you have a problem with your style properties. Please check  on your `container` and `inputcontainer` style properties. If you have any `ScrollView` in your `render` method add following

```
<ScrollView keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'>
```

Comment: I get the same results. No response

Comment: I have edited my answer. Have given sample working code. @Kevvv

Comment: Adding a child <View /> with { flex: 1 } made it work for me